# Which of these is the right way to do foreign keys?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, sqlite

So, i'm trying sqlite3 and i have a question about Foreign Keys and Indices.

Which of these methods is the right one ?

```
CREATE TABLE artist(
  artistid    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  artistname  TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE track(
  trackid     INTEGER,
  trackname   TEXT, 
  trackartist INTEGER REFERENCES artist
);
CREATE INDEX trackindex ON track(trackartist);
```

OR this one:

```
CREATE TABLE student(
  SudentID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  First TEXT,
  Last,
  Contact Text,
  Year INTEGER)

CREATE TABLE loan(
  StudentID INTEGER,
  ISBN INTEGER,
  out INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY(SudentID)
      REFERENCES student(SudentID)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
  PRIMARY KEY(StudentID, ISBN)
)
CREATE INDEX StudentID_Index ON student(StudentID)
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as it works, it's a style choice. IMHO coding the `REFERENCES` in-line on the column is better because it makes it more clear:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    username TEXT NOT NULL,
    pwhash TEXT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT,
    created INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE posts (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    id_user INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE INDEX posts_id_user ON posts(id_user);
```

Also. no need to code the primary key column of the foreign table - referencing just the table is enough (the primary key is assumed).

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/b837e).

Answer (score -1):

I think i found a solution.

I'm doing this:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, /* No need for 'autoincrement' keyword */
    username TEXT NOT NULL,
    pwhash TEXT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT,
    created INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE posts (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    id_user INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_user)
        REFERENCES users(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE INDEX users_posts ON posts(id_user);
```